# Example of DS with a dense trajectory in the whole state space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open and connected set. We assume there is a vector field $F \in \mathcal{C}^1(\overline{U})$ giving rise to a DS ($\overline{U}$ denotes the closure)
$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=F(\mathbf{x})$$
We set $\Gamma_{\mathbf{x}_0}=\{\mathbf{x}(t)|t \in I_{max}\}$ where $I_{max}$ is the maximal interval of existence.

---

**My question is the following:** Is there a DS/ can somebody give an example of a DS which has a dense trajectory in $\overline{U}$, i.e. $\overline{\Gamma_{x_0}}=\overline{U}$?

I am unable to come up with an example and wonder if something like this actually exists.

Comment: Cross posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750810/example-of-ds-with-a-dense-trajectory-in-the-whole-state-space?noredirect=1#comment10083122_4750810

Comment: For instance, the complement to the trefoil knot in $S^3$ admits an ergodic dynamical system,  the geodesic flow of the modular orbifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Very interesting. Could you point me to some reference?

Comment: I am not sure about your level. You can start by reading E.Ghys' plenary talk at ICM-2006 in Madrid. You also need to know that ergodicity of a flow implies that almost every orbit is dense.